# Options to refresh Sharepoint excel workbook programmatically

Tags: odata

We have setup a mechanism for our consumers to create oData feed based on certain choice of fields, and we have written an excel plugin to convert this oData URL to an excel workbook(or embed this oData into excel). Further the excel work book created is uploaded to sharepoint farm. oData URL can be scheduled to refresh periodically, we are looking for options to programmatically refresh workbook. Appreciate if you can share experience setting up something like this.

-
Thanks,
Gp